# What is meaning of "versus" in "RC circuits: V and I versus time"

Tags: meaning

Here is original text:

> - 1.4  Capacitors and ac circuits
>
>   - 1.4.1 Capacitors
>   - 1.4.2 *RC* circuits: *V* and *I* versus time
>   - 1.4.3 Differentiators
>   - 1.4.4 Integrators
>   - 1.4.5 Not quite perfect. . .

As a rule of thumb, in electronics "RC circuits: V and I versus time" should be means "in RC circuits, as time changes, V(Voltage) and I(current) vary accordingly." But at [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/versus) seems no sense that I mentioned.

Did I misunderstand something? Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about highly domain-specific terminology that wouldn't be understood by most native Anglophones.

Comment: This is very similar to your previous post asking about reactance and which has been moved to SE Physics, although IMHO it should be to SE Electrical Engineering as it's a basic question about electronics which almost any technical dictionary or text book should be able to answer. It's rarely a good idea to look up technical terms in a general purpose dictionary, however good it may be. Specialist use of language requires a specialist reference work.

Comment: @PeterJennings I'm sorry, English is not my native language. Now I realize that I have been using some ineffective learning methods. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the name of a section that deals with the ways that voltage (*V*) and current (*I*) vary with time in or around RC circuits. Another way to say it is "*V* and *I* **over** time". This information is often given in a graph.

In the case of OP, "versus" is expressing a relationship of *V* and *I* to time.

The linked [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/versus) entry is weak, as OP mentioned. However, the "relationship" is loosely included in the third definition: "used to compare two things or ideas"

As Michael Harvey commented, we can also say that we graph *V* and *I* **against** time.

Comment: What is meaning of "In this case" in you answer? It refer to "This information is often given in a graph" or "RC circuits: V and I versus time" in picture at my post? which case?

Comment: @Tom I meant to refer to the picture in your post. (I edited it now.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that "versus" necessarily always expresses a _proportional_ relationship, (I am not very good at maths). It may mean any quantitative or numerical relationship in general. If someone who knows better sees this, please comment to fix that.

Comment: That is right that your said "This information is often given in a graph." I see something related to function graphs and calculus.

Comment: We can produce a graph of x **against** y

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I understand. Thank you for your "against".

Comment: @Tom, I should have written that we plot y against x (e.g. V & I against time). It is the convention that we say that we plot the dependent quantity against the independent quantity.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ok, I understand what you mean. Thank you for you more details.